Closed-form solution for series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}$ involving square root of a factorial
We have $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$, however, we are facing
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}$ involving square root of a factorial.
Since $n!>n^{2}$ if $n\geq4$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}<\frac{1}{n}$, and
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n}=-\ln(1-a)$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{a^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}$ converges when $0<a<1$. Is there a closed-form
solution for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}$?

$\sum a^n/n$ only converges if $|a|<1,$ but it is fairly easy to show the original sequence converges for all $a.$

I doubt there is a closed form. There usually isn't.

Anyhow, this is a nice function (even if it does not show a closed form).

@Thomas Andrews, would you please write out the details that it converges for all $a$

@ChenDeng-Ta hint: $n! \geq (n / 2)^{n / 2}$
